# number as variable name in php

Tags: php, variables

number as variable name not possible right? But this works

```
 ${4} = 444;
 echo ${4};
```

Question: How much is this justified using this syntax? and where is info about this in documentation? I not found.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity: Why do you care?

Comment: I can't think of any time that a numerical variable number would be useful.

Comment: Angels and ministers of grace - defend us!

Comment: @Erwin Moller Just Out of sheer curiosity :)

Comment: It's the craziest thing I ever saw in php, that's for sure

Comment: class 3DFlipnote for handling flipnote studio 3d flipnotes in php

and I'm now here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is covered in [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). No, you are not "justified" in using this syntax. You should absolutely **never do this**, there is no good reason for using a number as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Variables between brackets are considered valid (variable variables), no matter the syntax.

```
${'sad asda sda'} = 444;
echo ${'sad asda sda'};
// still works.
```

Answer (score 1):

this is also works

```
$_4 = 444;
echo $_4;  //output 444.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly ok json string:

```
$json_str = '{"1": "One", "02": "Two"}';
```

So if I were to decode it:

```
$json_object = json_decode($json_str);
```

the way to access the elements is:

```
$one = $json_object->{1};
$two = $json_object->{"02"};
```